How to deserialize empty and null values of JSON in Jackson using not deprecated methods but overloaded variant that takes context argument?
I know about @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class) annotation on a field level.
I have this CustomDeserializer:
package com.custom_app.client_app.web.business.dictionary.control.deserializer;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import io.vavr.control.Try;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<String> {
    public CustomDeserializer() {
        super(String.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return Try.of(p::getText)
            .transform(value -> (value.isEmpty() || !value.get().matches("\\d{9}")) ?
                Try.of(() -> "FILL_FIELD") : value
            ).get();
    }
}

Too bad, null or empty values during deserialization aren't managed.
There is getEmptyValue() or getNullValue(), but they're both deprecated with adnotation: Since 2.6 Use overloaded variant that takes context argument.
I don't understand which overload variant the documentation is mentioning.
Anyone knows the correct way how to deserialize null and empty values without using @Deprecated methods?

Ok, found answer in newer version of Jackson's documentation.
This overriden method works for me:
@Override
public String getNullValue(DeserializationContext ctxt) {
    return "Test";
};

Now I see, that the particular property of JSON I get from backend on frontend, really has the desired alternative string instead of just plain null.
